# How handle NULL in visualization

Tags: qliksense

I have two tables (it is example, of course) that I loaded to app from different sources by script
Table 1:

| ID | Attribute T1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 200 |

Table 2:

| ID | Attribute T2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 |
| 2 | Value 2 |

On a list I create table:
ID
Attribute T1
Attribute T2

Finally I have table

| ID | Attribute T1 | Attribute T2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | Value 1 |
| 2 | - | Value 2 |
| 3 | 200 | - |

So, as You know it limits me in filtering and analyzing data, for example I can't show all data that isn't represented in Table 1, or all data for Attribute T1 not equal 100.

I try to use NullAsValue, but it didn't help. Would be appreciate for idea how to manage my case.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you're attempting, you'll need to `Join` or `Concatenate` your tables. The reason is because `Null` means something different depending on how the data is loaded.

There's basically two "types" of `Null`:

### "Implied" `Null`

When you associate several tables in your data model, as you've done in your example, Qlik is essentially treating that as a natural outer join between the tables. But since it's not an *actual* join that happens when the script executes, the `Null`s that arise from data incongruencies (like in your example) are basically implied, since there really is an absence of data there. There's nothing in the data or script that actually says "there are no `Attribute T1` values for `ID` of 2." Because of that, you can't use a function like `NullAsValue()` or `Coalesce()` to replace `Null`s with another value because those `Null`s aren't even there -- there's nothing to actually replace.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Data Model Viewer]

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Data Model Viewer]

The above tables don't have any *actual* `Null`s -- just implied ones from their association and the fact that the `ID` fields in either table don't have all the same values.

### "Realized" `Null`

If, instead of just using associations, you actually combine the tables using the `Join` or `Concatenate` prefixes, then Qlik is forced to actually generate a `Null` value in the absence of data. Instead of `Null` being implied, it's actually there in the data model -- it's been realized. In this case, we can actually use functions like `NullAsValue()` or `Coalesce()` or `Alt()` to replace `Null`s with another value since we actually have something in our table to replace.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Data Model Viewer]

The above joined table has *actual* `Null`s that are realized in the data model, so they can be replaced.

To replace `Null`s at that point, you can use the `NullAsValue()` or `Coalesce()` functions like this in the Data Load Editor:

```
table1:
load * inline [
ID  ,   Attribute T1
1   ,   100
3   ,   200
];


table2:
join load * inline [
ID  ,   Attribute T2
1   ,   Value 1
2   ,   Value 2
];


NullAsValue [Attribute T1];
Set NullValue = '-NULL-';

new_table:
NoConcatenate load
    ID
  , [Attribute T1]
  , Coalesce([Attribute T2], '-AlsoNULL-') as [Attribute T2]
Resident table1;

Drop Table table1;
```

That will result in a table like this:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Data Model Viewer]

The `Coalesce()` and `Alt()` functions are also available in chart expressions.

Here are some quick links to the things discussed here:

- [Qlik `Null` interpretation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/null-value-handling.htm)
- [Qlik table associations](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/associations-between-logical-tables.htm)
- [`NullAsValue()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/NullAsValue.htm)
- [`Coalesce()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/coalesce.htm)
- [`Alt()` function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ConditionalFunctions/alt.htm)

Comment: It seems to me QLIK don't make my task easy. :(

Comment: It can definitely be confusing at first, but once you see it enough you start to recognize the pattern of what's going on. Either way, if my answer was helpful, please mark the answer as being “correct” to help others find it in the future :)